# Como fazer o output no Tkinter do python sair dessa forma?

Tags: python, tkinter, gui, ux

Basicamente, estou fazendo um contador no python e resolvi fazer uma GUI, mas queria que os resultados fossem printados dentro da GUI, e não no console do meu VSCODE, como posso realizar isso?
Os números apareceriam em sequencia, um ao lado do outro a cada 0.1 segundos.

Exemplo de input:

```
inicio: 0

fim: 10

passo: 2
```

Exemplo de output:

```
0 2 4 6 8 10
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

#declara função do contador para usar mais tarde no GUI

def contador ():

    #informações de inicio fim e passos do contador

    inicio = int(entrada_dados_inicio.get())
    fim = int(entrada_dados_fim.get())
    passo = int(entrada_dados_passo.get())

    #contagem regressiva
    if inicio > fim:
        for i in range(inicio, fim -1, -passo):

            #aqui está o problema (linha 20), como posso fazer esse caralhudinho desse print aparecer na GUI e não no console?

            print(i, end = ' ', flush = True)
            time.sleep(0.1)
        print('')
        
    #contagem normal 
    else:
        for i in range(inicio, fim + 1, passo):

            #este também

            print(i, end = ' ', flush = True)
            time.sleep(0.1)
        print('')

#criar janela e textos
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('contador')
nome_aba = tk.Label(text="bem vindo ao contador!")
começo_texto  = tk.Label(text="começo")
fim_texto = tk.Label(text="fim")
passo_texto = tk.Label(text="passo")

#criar entradas de dados
entrada_dados_inicio = tk.Entry(fg="black", bg="white", width=25)
entrada_dados_fim = tk.Entry(fg="black", bg="white", width=25)
entrada_dados_passo = tk.Entry(fg="black", bg="white", width=25)

#criar botão
botão = tk.Button(
    text =  'Faça sua contagem!',
    width=25,
    height=5,
    bg="white",
    fg="black",
    command = contador
)

#organizar GUI
nome_aba.pack(pady=5)
botão.pack()
começo_texto.pack()
entrada_dados_inicio.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
fim_texto.pack()
entrada_dados_fim.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
passo_texto.pack()
entrada_dados_passo.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

#termina o programa
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Crie um label, ou outro widget de exibição de texto, e a cada iteração ao invés de *printar* atualiza e texto do label.

Answer (score 0):

Como já foi dito, é necessário criar uma Label caso queira que apareça em sua interface da seguinte forma :

```
lb_contagem = tk.Label(text='Contagem')
lb_contagem.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
```

E em seu contador adicione isto:

```
for i in range(inicio, fim + 1, passo):
    lb_contagem.config(text=i)
    window.update()
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).